# Testing nativescript-vue apps with a connected android device

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nativescript

I'm new to nativescript and mobile developing and I want to start developing nativescript apps, instead of using emulators I want to use my own mobile phone, I succesfully activated dev mode and USB debuggin and the tns device android command succesfully lists my android phone.

```
Connected devices & emulators
Searching for devices...
iTunes is not installed. Install it on your system and run this command again.
┌───┬────────────────┬──────────┬───────────────────┬────────┬───────────┬─────────────────┐
│ # │ Device Name    │ Platform │ Device Identifier │ Type   │ Status    │ Connection Type │
│ 1 │ grandneove3gxx │ Android  │ 4b134ce68306924e  │ Device │ Connected │ USB             │
└───┴────────────────┴──────────┴───────────────────┴────────┴───────────┴─────────────────┘
```

Now I created my first app with command:

```
vue init nativescript-vue/vue-cli-template testapp
```

Installed all dependencies with:

```
npm install
```

And right now I'm stuck, how can I begin to preview my app in my phone while I change and debug stuff like I normally do with web apps? is there a npm run watch equivalent.

After reading a bit I used tns build android but now the commadn prompt tells me to scan a qr code and download playground app, is that really needed?

Comment: If you are using preview, you would need Playground app, scan the QR code to see the app on device. If you are building locally, you can directly install on connected device. Playground is generally used to quickly test a code or build app even without setting up Android SDK on local machine. Also by default HMR is turned on, but Vue has few known issues with HMR.

Comment: I'm using local, I installed all dependencies needed (java,android sdk...), how can I install in my phone?

Comment: Just `tns run android` should do the job.

Comment: I did that and got this error: Unable to apply changes on device: 4b134ce68306924e. Error is: The device is not authorized. Please use the --emulator flag to run the application on on an emulator. I'm not using an emulator but a real connected device

Comment: When you connect the device first time, you will have to enable developer options and allow machine to connect (a popup will be shown on your device). Did you do all that too?

Comment: yes, I enabled dev mode and USB debugging. I run tns android run --device 1 and get Webpack compilation complete. Watching for file changes.
Webpack build done!
Project successfully prepared (android)
Unable to apply changes on device: 4b134ce68306924e. Error is: The device is not authorized. Please use the --emulator flag to run the application on on an emulator.

Comment: Understood but did you receive the popup asking for permission, just like iPhone when connected to a Mac if you had noticed.

Comment: well a popup did show asking me to use my phone as a multimedia device (I chose this) or a PTP camera

Comment: Which version of Android you have? Do you see USB Debugging notification on notification bar, it appears while it's connected always.

Comment: samsung galaxy grand neos with android 4.4